# expected const char * but argument is of type char

Tags: c, pointers, struct, strcmp, strcpy

This error keeps popping up and I don't know how to solve it.
Please help!  the error pops up in this line: 
`---fscanf(ifp, "%s", archive.team[i].color);---`

There is also a 
 `"passing argument 2 of strcmp makes pointer from integer without a cast"`
error in line:
 
`---if (strcmp(archive.team[j].name, name) == 0){---`

Here is a condensed version of my code----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dragon {
    char name[40] ;
    char color[40] ;
};
struct collection {
    struct dragon team[1000];
    int num_dragons;
};

int main() {

struct collection archive;

FILE * ifp = fopen("dragon.txt", "r");
int i, j, k, l, m, updates, n=0;
char directions, color, name, ADD, REMOVE, SEARCH, LIST, rem;

fscanf(ifp, "%d", &updates);
for (i=0; i<updates; i++){
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", directions);

    if (directions==ADD){
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", archive.team[i].name);
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", archive.team[i].color);
        printf("%s the %s has been added to the team.", archive.team[i].name, archive.team[i].color);
    }

   else if (directions==REMOVE){
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", name);
        for (j=0; j<updates; j++){
            if (strcmp(archive.team[j].name, name) == 0){
                strcpy(archive.team[j].name, "rem");
                strcpy(archive.team[j].color, "rem");
                printf("%s the %s has been removed from the team.", name, archive.team[j].color);
            }
        }
    }

    else if (directions==SEARCH){
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", name);
        for (k=0; k<updates; k++){
            if (strcmp(archive.team[k].name, name) == 0)
            printf("%s the dragon is currently on the team.", name);
        }
        for (l=0; l<updates; l++){
            if (strcmp(archive.team[l].name, name) == 0)
                n++;
        }
        if (n==0)
            printf("%s the dragon is NOT currently on the team.", name);

    }

    else if (directions==LIST){
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", color);
        printf("%s dragons:\n", color);
        for (m=0; m<updates; m++){
            if (strcmp(archive.team[m].color, color) == 0)
            printf("%s\n", archive.team[m].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaration of `archive` ?

Comment: Please write a complete verifiable code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "A condensed version" of your code is no good if you leave out the important parts, and leave in nonsense like `enter code here`.

Comment: `char ... name` - there's your problem, just like the error said. It's a `char`, when you need a `char *`, or an array of `char`. Same goes for `color`. You got it right in your `struct`, you just have to do the same outside of it.

Comment: Get a condensed version of the answer: the error is in the part you have skipped.

Comment: I tried using char * name[] and char * color[] in the structure declaration but it still didn't compile

Comment: Change `char name` to `char name[40];`

Comment: The first error is [at line 23](http://ideone.com/3fo4P6).

Comment: Changing it to char name [40] got rid of the error, but as the program compiles to the screen, it crashes

Comment: Read the warnings. All warnings are errors unless you can prove otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration:

```
char directions, color, name, ADD, REMOVE, SEARCH, LIST, rem;
```

is totally wrong. You try to write a string to a single char. Even if you manage to compile that, execution of such code would cause a buffer overrun and unexpected behavior (AV most likely).

Comparisons

```
if (directions==ADD)
```

are also quite suspect, you compare some data with uninitialized char, which would not work for the obvious reasons.
Usage of the fixed length arrays is also not very good idea, because any string greater than 39 symbols will cause buffer overruns.

Honestly, a recommend you rewrite your code using std::string for string storage and std::cin/cout for the input/output.

Lets analyze your code from the beginning: you define variable direction, which should describe what action should be performed on your data. This variable is a char, but you try to write some sting into it, so you most likely will get AV here. Then you try to compare your data with some ADD variable which had never been initialized, so contains random char from the stack.

To make current solution workable:
1. Change direction declaration to the `char[40]`;
2. Change ADD to `char* ADD = "ADD";` (REMOVE, SEARCH, etc should be changed the same way);
3. Change comparison code to `if(!strcmp(directions, ADD))`

Comment: Ah I apologize. I'm a beginner programmer and this is one of my assignments I'm stuck on. How would I rewrite my char declarations so that it compiles, and how would I initialize the uninitialized char?

Comment: Honestly, problem is much deeper than char declaration. Lets analyze your code from the beginning:

Answer (score 1):

I think these are the lines which gives the error

```
 fscanf(ifp, "%s", name);
 fscanf(ifp, "%s", directions);
```

and not

```
 fscanf(ifp, "%s", archive.team[i].color);
```

because

```
 name is of type `char` and not `char []`.
```

Again, here

```
 strcmp(archive.team[j].name, name)
```

the 2nd param should be of type `char []` but it is of type `char`.

The problem is here

```
char directions, color, name, ADD, REMOVE, SEARCH, LIST, rem;
```

`color` and `name` probably need to be arrays, for eg.

```
char directions, color[40], name[40], ADD, REMOVE, SEARCH, LIST, rem;
```

Comment: I was thinking that could've been it. Any suggestions on how to fix it syntax-wise?

Comment: @DavidT - added the correct declaration for `color` and `name`.

Comment: I tried that. It got rid of the errors, but it crashes while it's compiling to the screen. I'm guessing that could be from other errors?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you forgot to close [the main function properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKHIo.png) too

Comment: it might be helpful link but it is still comment.